# Is it possible/safe to downgrade from Thunderbird 3.0 Beta 4 to Thunderbird 2?

Tags: thunderbird

I wanted to try out the Thunderbird 3.0 Beta 4 because I have some issues with Thundebird 2 that I know are fixed in 3.0.

The question is, is it possible to downgrade from Thunderbird 3.0 to 2.0 or are there any problems with the preferences or mail format (I read somewhere that Tb3 uses a sqLite database for some of its storage)?

According to http://www.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/thunderbird/3.0b4/releasenotes/ it is possible to remove the application itself, but it does not say anything about data compatibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Thunderbird 3.0 - New Features and Changes](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Thunderbird_3.0_-_New_Features_and_Changes#Reverting_to_Thunderbird_2.0) page has some information about this:

> While it is not recommended, you can use the same profile with both Thunderbird 2.0.0.x and the latest nightly build for Shredder (i.e Tb3), and switch back and forth between versions.

Some caveats:

> The main impact is that not all add-ons work with both versions [...] and that your cookies and passwords are stored in different files in Shredder, so if you reverted you'd use the (old) Thunderbird 2 versions of those files.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a backup of the Thunderbird profile folder before the upgrade and change all your account settings to leave messages on the server. That way if you need to rollback you will have your old profile and the messages can be downloaded again from the server.